# Adding a images behind header react-native

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-native-swiper

I want to add multiple images behind header with a swiper. I tried implementing this using `Native-base` and `react-native-swiper`. However, what was resulted is, as following.

[image]

Following is my code

```
<View style={{flex:1, elevation:2}}>
                    <Swiper style={StyleSheet.flatten( {backgroundColor: '#fff'})}>
                    <ImageBackground
                        source={require('../../img/auth_background.png')}
                        style={this.styles.backgroundStyle}
                        imageStyle={this.styles.backgroundImage}
                    >
                        <Header style={{
                            marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                        }}>
                            <StatusBar
                                backgroundColor={Colors.statusBar}
                                barStyle="light-content"
                            />
                            <Left>
                                <Button transparent onPress={this.handleBackButtonClick} small={true}>
                                    <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' size={30} color={Colors.textWhite}/>
                                </Button>
                            </Left>
                            <Body/>
                            <Right/>
                        </Header>
                    </ImageBackground>
                        <ImageBackground
                            source={require('../../img/auth_background.png')}
                            style={this.styles.backgroundStyle}
                            imageStyle={this.styles.backgroundImage}
                        >
                            <Header style={{
                                marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
                                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                borderBottomWidth: 0, shadowOffset: {height: 0, width: 0},
                                shadowOpacity: 0, elevation: 0
                            }}>
                                <StatusBar
                                    backgroundColor={Colors.statusBar}
                                    barStyle="light-content"
                                />
                                <Left>
                                    <Button transparent onPress={this.handleBackButtonClick} small={true}>
                                        <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' size={30} color={Colors.textWhite}/>
                                    </Button>
                                </Left>
                                <Body/>
                                <Right/>
                            </Header>
                        </ImageBackground>
                    </Swiper>
</View>
```

I want to fix the header so that it won't also swipe with the images. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `zIndex` and `position`. I guess there is some issue when using native-base `header` and `container` with `zIndex`.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={{flex:1, zIndex: 2, position: 'absolute', marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight, marginLeft:'2%'}}>
                       <Button iconLeft transparent>
                               <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' size={30} color={Colors.textWhite}/>
                       </Button>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{width: '100%', height: '50%', zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute'}}>
                        <Swiper style={StyleSheet.flatten( {backgroundColor: '#fff',zIndex:1, flex:1})}>
                            <ImageBackground
                                source={require('../../img/auth_background.png')}
                                style={this.styles.backgroundStyle}
                                imageStyle={this.styles.backgroundImage}
                            >

                            </ImageBackground>
                            <ImageBackground
                                source={require('../../img/auth_background.png')}
                                style={this.styles.backgroundStyle}
                                imageStyle={this.styles.backgroundImage}
                            >
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </Swiper>
                    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

React-Native-Swiper in android will display blank content when swiper height and width aren't shown.
please add fixed height and width to view or to the swiper

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `Header` outside `Swiper` and make its position `absolute`

```
<Header style={{
        marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        position:'absolute',
        top:0,
        left:0
}}>
```

Comment: I tried this, but then I didn't see the header at all

Comment: try by giving height and width, and make sure you are defining it after `<Swiper>`, not above it

Comment: height and width to `<Swiper>`?